# Use Json.Net instead of Syste.Text:Json in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net, system.text.json

We want to use Json.Net instead System.Text.Json in our project, mainly because we must use the TypeNameHandling function.

The app has the following:

- It's a console app.
- It uses Dependency Injection.

Question: how can we tell the runtime to use Json.Net in serialization/deserialization instead of System.Text.Json?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add code showing how do you set up your DI.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert it in your project from Nuget Package manager. There is no obstacle to install in a Console application.
For dependency injection you can follow directions [in this link.](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithDependencyInjection.htm)